# Php multiple mod rewrite rule conflict

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, conflict

I'm trying clean my url from

`localhost/xxx/profile.php?name=google` to

```
localhost/xxx/google
```

Below is my htaccess file

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /creatorsink/
    RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ profile.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

If i remove `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]` it's working properly, if i do so then url not opening without .php extension

Is there any way to use both without conflicting each other.

Answer (score 0):

Ordering of rule is causing problem. Your first rule is grabbing every URI. Reverse the order and make your first rule little more smart.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /creatorsink/

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/creatorsink/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, But unfortunately it's not working. Check my question for updated .htaccess modifications. Any guess where i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: As you can see my answer that you need to add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` line also in your 2nd rule

Comment: No luck so far,.. Now getting issues with .php removal. kindly check my above edit for updated htaccess file contents.

Comment: yes it's in my root directory i.e under foler htdocs/creatorsink